# Is it possible to convert m2ts with Dolby Vision into mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, vision, dolby

Is it possible to convert a m2ts with dual layer Dolby Vision information into an MP4 without any loss of the information?

Answer (score 1):

1.Conversion at full HD resolution (same as the source file).

> ffmpeg -i inputfile.m2ts -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -coder ac
>   -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -deinterlace -b:v 3000k -cmp +chroma -g 250 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -flags +loop outputfile.mp4

2. conversion at lower resolution.

> ffmpeg -i inputfile.m2ts -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -coder ac
>   -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -deinterlace -s 720x576 -b:v 1600k -cmp +chroma -g 250 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -b_strategy 1 -flags +loop outputfile.mp4

3. conversion 1440x1080i (Anamophic) to FHD 1920x1080p (MP4).

If your camera records HD in 1440x1080, (non-square pixels or anamorphic) you can add the re-size and aspect ratio to make it 1920x1080 square pixels. A square pixel is easier on LCD monitors. (You basically change the pixel-aspect-ratio from wide pixel to square pixel)

> ffmpeg -i InputFile.mt2s -acodec libfaac -ar 48000 -ab 128k -coder ac
>   -vcodec libx264 -threads 0 -deinterlace -s 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -b:v 3000k -cmp +chroma -g 250 -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8
>   -i_qfactor 0.71 -keyint_min 25 -r 25 -b_strategy 1 -flags +loop OutputFile.mp4